# pmap inconsistent behavior?

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

Compare

```
mtcars %>% mutate(a = pmap(list(gear, carb), sum))
```

which "works" as expected, with

```
mtcars %>% mutate(a = pmap(list(gear, carb), mean))
```

which does not.

I am obviously missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference has to do with the function interface: `sum()` accepts any number of arguments (often referred to as "dots"), while `mean()` expects a vector:

```
sum( 1, 2, 3 )       # 6
mean( c(1,2,3) )     # 2
```

To use a vector-based function like `mean()` with `pmap()`, you can [lift its domain](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/lift.html) from vector to dots:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(a = pmap(list(gear, carb), lift_vd(mean)))    # Now works as expected
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Very grately appreciated.